# Get-PnPView : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powershell, list-view, pnp-powershell

I need PnP command to check if view exist on list before creating view.

```
Get-PnPView -List "list1"-Identity "view1"
```

However, I am getting below error if view doesn't exists. If view exists, it works fine.

> Get-PnPView : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have PSVersion "5.1.19041.906" installed on my machine. I am running the command in Admin. mode and I can successfully connect to SP Online.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$listView = Get-PnPView -List "list1" -Identity "view1"

if($listView -ne $null)
{  
    Write-Host -f Green "List view exist!"
}
else
{
    Write-Host -f Yellow "List view does not exist!"
}
```

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPView](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPView.html)

Comment: same result...though it goes to next line as per condition but error is thrown in console "Get-PnPView : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I have observed the same error as well, even with the latest version of PnP PowerShell. Suggesting you to create an issue at the [PnP PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues) repo so that repo contributors or maintainers will help you quickly & more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the display name for list and its view. After that, you can check whether the view exists or not as Ganesh mentioned above.

```
$listDisplayName = "list 1"
$viewDisplayName = "view 1"
Get-PnPView -List $listDisplayName -Identity $viewDisplayName
```

Comment: I have tried with display name ONLY for both component. Same result